# Allow to add all possible options to the site menu for iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

In iOS app you are allowed to select up to 4 items as site options:

> [image: ipad]

This limitation happening due to screen width when app is used on the phone or in split view mode for iPad:

> [image: splitview]

My request is to allow to select all of items simultaneously for the site submenu and show all selected items if the space is enough (like on the first picture when items aligned vertically in the main toolbar, there is no limit in space due to scrolling). Items that are not selected will be available via <kbd>...</kbd> as well as early. Alternative solution would be is to scroll items horizontally if they don’t fit in width, but I think it’s harder to implement.